# Display flicker on new HP 14S laptop with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation, display, flicker

Dual boot installation on new HP 14S laptop using latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a USB stick. The machine has Intel i5 processor with Intel iRIS Xe graphics. When running from the USB it is necessary to select safe graphics mode when booting to prevent the intolerable screen flicker and bleeding of parts of the image. Once Ubuntu is installed it is necessary to enter the recovery mode and then resume normal boot to eliminate the problem.
The advice on this type of problem on askubuntu is extensive and varied. I would appreciate some guidance on the most likely cause and solution.

Comment: Try a 21.10 live session. If it works fine then you can install it instead of 20.04. Your hardware is newer than 20.04 thus require a newer kernel.

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto for your answer.  You were right, a 21.10 live session ran just fine so I have installed it.  If I could work out how to accept your answer then I would do so.

Comment: It was posted as a comment but now that you confirmed I can also post as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware on HP 14S with, its latest generation Intel i5 and companion IRIS Xe graphics, is newer than the Ubuntu 20.04 release. Support for this hardware has been added in newer kernels than the one being shipped with Ubuntu 20.04 at the time of this writing.

Solution: Install Ubuntu 21.10.

In a few months, April 2022, you'll be able to do an online upgrade to the next LTS release 22.04, supported for 5 years.